# The very first appearance of concept of a Tensor.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, math-history, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I really would like to know the very first appearance of the concept of a Tensor.
Because I read that was on the studies of stress on materials by Bernoulli conversely other times by Gibbs.
I have also another question: about the very first appearance of a rigorous and well-defined structure of Tensor products or other "modern definitions" using linear algebra. I read that was Cartan that have made this "axiomatization" (from old differential geometry to differential forms and then to tensor concept).

Feel free to use mathematics as you pleased.

Comment: here a little bunch of ideas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#History and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann#Response

Answer (score 0):

The differential theory of tensors was created by Ricci-Cubastro with his "Absolute Differential Calculus" heavely criticized as useless for 30 years before Einstein used it in the general theory of relativity. Levi-Civita has extended it.

In that same period of Bernoulli there was Euler who conceived the concept of interial tensor in his *Theoria Motus Corporum Solidorum seu Rigidorum* (Theory of the Movement of the Solid and Rigid Bodies) published in 1760. While the term "tensor" probably has been coined very later by Hamilton in *On some extensions of Quaternions.* Philosophical magazine (4th series), vol. 7, pp. 492-499; vol. 8 (1854), pp. 125-137, 261-269; vol. 9 (1855), pp. 46-51, 280-290

Comment: But when and where, the concept of Tensor was born?

Comment: Edited my answer adding some clues